# Problem cloning a project from Github to Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, github, egit, cloning

When I clone a project from Github to Eclipse I get two cloned projects in eclipse with different organization although they seem to have the same content, I do not understand what is happening.
Eclipse:
[image]

Github:
[image]

[image]

the project has Maven implemented, it is possible that it is part of the bug

I want to have a single proyect as it appears in GitHub

Comment: You have `pom.xml` in both root of the repository and in `my-app` folder so eclipse imported both as maven project. This is default behavior for multi module projects.

Comment: In the menu of the _Project Explorer_ you can choose _Projects Presentation > Hierarchical_ to show nested projects as nested projects instead of one below the other. By the way, the theme you have is hard to read and the plugin providing the theme tries to cheat the Eclipse open source license by patching Eclipse at runtime (or to be more precise via loadtime weaving). This can cause issues and slow down Eclipse. Consider using a more ergonomic theme that doesn't have such issues if you don't like the themes built-in.

Comment: @howlger what do you mean with the thing of the theme?? Do you mean The DevStye??